# Low storage space and 65gb in System dir?

Tags: macos, storage

I have noticed lately that I've been lacking any space on my MacBook. I've looked at the storage data and noticed my System dir is taking up 65gb, on looking up online this issue the culprit is usually the snapshots/backup folder however mine is empty.

I then ran `sudo du -d 1 -x -c -g /` to list the files and their space usage and got the following:

```
1   /home
0   /Developer
3   /usr
du: /.Spotlight-V100: Operation not permitted
1   /net
0   /.PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware
1   /bin
0   /Network
1   /sbin
du: /Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC: Operation not permitted
9   /Library
7   /System
1   /.fseventsd
4   /private
1   /.DocumentRevisions-V100
0   /.vol
46  /Users
10  /Applications
1   /opt
1   /dev
0   /Volumes
3   /anaconda3
0   /cores
80  /
80  total
```

Most of it seems somewhat normal to me (I have 120gb available net), do any of these dir's seem slightly off to any of you?